# c# Compiling errors: CS0122 & CS1061

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, msbuild

Screenshot of the console (Italian) https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpYWD.jpg

The first error says "'RtmpClient.ConnectAsync()' is inaccessible due to its protection level”

The file can be found [here](https://github.com/snowl/Poro/blob/master/Poro/PoroLib/Forwarder/ForwardPlayer.cs#L52)

The second one it seems that: *RtmpServer does not contain any definitions about Clients and no argument has been found that accepts RtmpServer*

I've noticed that they all refer to [PoroLib.csproj](http://pastebin.com/pCYDehbB)

I've checked evererything, I got the .dlls and the NuGet packages

I don't have VB2013 but I remember that I've managed to compile it with msbuild in the past and I need it now, here's the string I use (in case you might need it)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe" Poro.sln /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

I hope someone has an answer for at least one of my problems :) have a nice day!

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: At first glance, I don't immediately see the issue.  Trying to build, but which project is XMPPP?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing some code (added // before it)